# How to print milliseconds in C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I want to print time in the format hh:mm:ss:ms(milliseconds). I could print in the form of hh:mm:ss. What can be the way to print remaining milliseconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<sys/timeb.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void) {
    struct timeb tp;
    ftime(&tp);
    char timeString[80];
    strftime(timeString, sizeof(timeString), "%H:%M:%S", localtime(&tp.time));
    printf("%s:%d", timeString, tp.millitm);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in linux ...

```
struct timeval tv;
gettimeofday(&tv,0);
time_t long_time;
struct tm *newtime;
time(&long_time);
newtime = localtime(&long_time);
char result[100] = {0};
sprintf(result, "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03ld", newtime->tm_hour,newtime->tm_min,newtime->tm_sec, (long)tv.tv_usec / 1000);
return result;
```

I have no experience working in windows .. try to find similar calls ..

Comment: this isn't useful because he specifically said Windows, thus the downvote.

Comment: @ScottM. time.h is there in Windows too. See [this](http://suacommunity.com/dictionary/gettimeofday-entry.php#id385598)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the MSDN library, you could try

```
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime( pointerToSetToTime );
```

Which sets a pointer argument to the current system time in 100-nanosecond intervals.